# Add another Word in TextView Android

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I have one sentence with 3 `TextView` in my RecyclerView. The picture is like below :

[image]

In that picture, I have one sentence in 3 `TextView`, there are "1" "HOT, MORE CHILLI" and "Pizza". This is my RecyclerView Binding code :

```
try {
    view.txtArticlesName.setText(/*orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("quantityValue") +*/
                            /*orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("spesial-request").replaceAll("[\\\"\\[\\]]", "") + */
                                    orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("bezeich"));
   view.txtQty.setText(orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("quantityValue"));
   view.txtReqList.setText(orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("spesial-request").replaceAll("[\\\"\\[\\]]", ""));

   } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I want to Join all of `TextView` with only one 'TextView` dynamicly. I'll try this :

```
view.txtArticlesName.setText(/*orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("quantityValue") +*/
                            /*orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("spesial-request").replaceAll("[\\\"\\[\\]]", "") + */
                                    orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("bezeich"));
```

But its not work, its not bind the data, so the `TextView` just show the default text "Hello World". Can `TextView` do this? I read about [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) too but i dont know how its work to add new word in one `TextView`. Or there is another way to do this? Any suggest and answer will helpfull for me. Thanks before.

Comment: maybe you have exception. and this code is never executed. just see the log cat or use Log to ensure that all this code is executed

Comment: @farazkhonsari My Log not show anything wrong. When i click pizza or another food from another RecyclerView itss success ad to this RecyclerView but the TextView just only show "Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a little disappointed . Here my final code :

```
try {
    view.txtArticlesName.setText(orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("quantityValue") + " " +
        orderList.getJSONObject(position).optString("spesial-request").replaceAll("[\\\"\\[\\]]", "") + " " +
        orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("bezeich"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

with getString :

[image: with getString]

with optString :

[image: with optString]

I change `getString` with `optString` and operator `+` work now. I'm not fully undertand why `getString` not work but `optString` work.

Thank you very much for all anwser, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

Simply concat the Strings in your TextView.

```
String string1 = "Hello", string2 = "HOT CHILLI", string3 = "PIZZA";

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textView);
textView.setText(string1.concat(string2).concat(string3));
```

Or you could also append it to the existing TextView's text.

```
textView.setText(textView.getText().toString.concat(string2));
```

**EDIT:**

Collect the data from the server in String variables, and then pass those variables to the TextView.

```
String string1, string2, string3;


try {
    string1 = orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("quantityValue");
    string2 = orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("spesial-request").replaceAll("[\\\"\\[\\]]", "");
    string3 = orderList.getJSONObject(position).getString("bezeich"));
    String final = string1.concat(string2).concat(string3);
    view.txtView.setText(final);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: its not work, my `TextView` not bind the data from my server

Comment: thanks for answer, i think its not work if we still use `getString`. I post my answer below. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use `'+'` operator or `StringBuilder` to join 2 or more strings and set the resultant string into a single textview.

If you want to have some part of text with different font, color, size, bold etc, you can use `Spannable` string or `Html.fromHtml()`

Comment: + operator its not work for me and i dont know why. I will try your suggest about String Builder

Answer (score 1):

you can make and use  spannable String like below :

```
 private void addSpannableString(){

        //"1" "HOT, MORE CHILLI" and "Pizza"
        String one= "1";
        String two=  "HOT, MORE CHILLI";
        String three= "Pizza";
        String mergeString= one + two + three;
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString( mergeString );
        StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
        spannable.setSpan( boldSpan, mergeString.indexOf(two), mergeString.indexOf(three), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
        textview.setText(mergeString);
    }
```

There are many methods are available to make Spans including colors and Typefaces

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextView.append(CharSequence text)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) to add more text to it.

> Append the specified text to the TextView's display buffer, upgrading
>   it to BufferType.EDITABLE if it was not already editable

---

Answer (score 1):

The Difference between `GetString` And `OptString` is:

From [Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150101212410/http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String))

> OptString returns the empty string ("") if the key you specify doesn't
>   exist. GetString on the other hand throws a JSONException.

Use `getString` if it's an error for the data to be missing, or `optString` if you're not sure if it will be there.

Comment: if that so, why we dont always use `optString` ?

Comment: When data is necessary to show..should use Getstring..it is also helpful for debug..if any values is missing in JOSN

Comment: My `TextView` show "Hello World" because there is no key string with "quantityValue", i got it now. Thanks for great explantion +1